# Remote sudo, execute a command and write output in local terminal

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, sudo

What I try to do, I connect to a remote server as a normal user with sudo right, then sudo to root, and execute a command & see output in my local terminal. I wrote a small script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_argument=$1
ssh -t username@hostname 'sudo su -; /path_to_my_script $1'
```

I type the password twice (one for ssh, the other for sudo), but I see nothing in my local terminal, and script looks terminated in remote  host. I believe second problem could be resolved by using exit, but I am a little bit confused how I can get this output to my local terminal.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String inside '' is taken literally. So, you are passing the dollar sign and 1 as a parameter to the script. If you want the string to be interpreted, place it inside "", like:

```
ssh -t username@hostname "sudo /path_to_my_script $1"
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that your answer fixes an *additional* problem by passing the script directly to `sudo`. The original command would have executed an interactive sudo shell first (`sudo su -`) and then, only after typing interactive `exit` to exit that shell, would have invoked the script in a NON-sudo context.

Comment: Good answer. If you want to make script complete non interactive (means why you have to type passwords whenever script runs) go for expect [Click here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/)